# Error "Illegal string offset" After PHP Upgrade

Tags: php

Warning [2] Illegal string offset 'title' - Line: 66

```
if(!isset($params['title'])) {
    $params['title'] = "Hidden Content";
  }
```

and Warning [2] Illegal string offset 'title' - Line: 3

```
  eval("\$return = \"".$templates->get("lock_wrapper")."\";");
```

Page where i am getting error : https://findjobsarkari.in/showthread.php?tid=1
Full Code of file here: https://pastebin.com/rBZEmJc8

Comment: Try to use:    isset($a['title']) !== false instead of !isset($params['title'])

Answer (score 0):

Try to change :

```
if(!isset($params['title'])) {
    $params['title'] = "Hidden Content";
}
```

To

```
$params['title'] = $params["title] ?? "Hidden Content";
```

Comment: Try `if(@!isset($params['title'])) {` instead of `if(!isset($params['title'])) {`